# Using timer in main class

Tags: java, timer, program-entry-point

Im creating a program which starts with a log-in formula . I want to make the whole program to stop and show this log-in formula again after 5 hours. To do that im using Timer.

```
public class MainClass implements ActionListener{

private final Timer timer = new Timer(30000, this);

public static void main(String args[]){
    timer.start();
    new JLogin();
}

//If time time-out
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    timer.stop();
    new Mainclass();
}
```

When im writing that it shows me errors when im calling "timer.start()" . The error says : "change modifier of timer() in static(). 
Any reason of happenning this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`timer` is an instance variable, so it can only be accessed via an instance of `MainClass`. You need to create an instance first:

```
MainClass mainClass = new MainClass();
mainClass.timer.start();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `new MainClass().timer.start()`

You can also do this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    new MainClass().begin();
}

private void begin() {
    timer.start();
    new JLogin();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

static method(main) cannot have instance variables (timer)